# MongoDB, BSONError: cyclic dependency detected

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, discord.js

While I was writing a Discord bot, I suddenly started getting an error that I don't know why. When I searched, I was able to find solutions for 'mongoose', not 'mongodb'. Below are the codes of the index, mongo and the faulty section I used.

No matter how hard I researched the problem, I couldn't solve it. Also, don't be intimidated by the length of the code, if you look carefully, I just spread the code, otherwise there isn't much.

part of code

```
async start (recall: boolean = false) {
        console.log('Starting server...');
        if (recall && !this.started) {
            // ...
        } else if (this.started) {
            // ...
            } else if (!this.database) {
            // ...
            } else {
                let { connections } = this;
                connections = connections.map((connection: any) => {
                    const userStyle = parseInt(connection?.user?.style) || 0;
                    const userXp = parseInt(connection?.user?.xp) || 0;
                    const userPrevWars = Math.max(parseInt(connection?.user?.prevWars.length) || 0, 1);
                    const userLevel = XPtoLevel(userXp);


                    const parser = LeveltoXP(userXp);
                    const Rate = [Math.pow(userPrevWars, 1.125),Math.pow(userStyle, 0.875)];
                    const userPower = Math.max(
                        (Math.sqrt(100 + 8 * userXp) * Rate[0] * userStyle * (parser + userXp)) / 26 * parser * Rate[1],
                        1
                    );

                    return {
                        ...connection,
                        user: {
                            ...connection.user,
                            power: userPower
                        }
                    };
                });
                const avarage = connections.reduce((a,b) => a + (b?.user.power || 0)) / connections.length;
                const pointerPower = avarage * Math.random() / 2 + avarage / 2;
                
                connections?.forEach(async (connection: any, index: number) => {
                    const current = connection.user.power;
                    const enemy = connections[([1,0])[index]].user.power;
                    const chance = current / (current + enemy);
                    const win = pointerPower < current;

                    connection?.message?.reply('The match is starting! Please wait...');
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        
                        connection?.message?.reply(`Your power is ${current}, enemy power is ${enemy}. \n Your chance to win is ${Math.round(chance * 10) * 10}%`);
                        setTimeout(async () => {
                            connection?.message?.reply(`You ${win ? 'win' : 'lost'} the match!`);
                            
                            connection.user.xp += Math.max(
                                10,
                                Math.floor(Math.round(
                                    Math.abs(current - enemy) * enemy / current * (win ? 1 : 0.5)
                                ) * 100) / 100
                            );
                            connection.user.prevWars.push({
                                user: connection.user,
                                result: 'win',
                                time: new Date().getTime(),
                                xp: connection.user.xp,
                                enemy
                            });
                            console.log(connection.user);
                            await this.database.updateOne({ id: connection.user.id }, { $set: { xp: connection.user.xp, prevWars: connection.user.prevWars } });

                            this.removeConnection(connection);
                        }, 3000);
                    }, 1000)
                });
            }
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
```

mongo.ts

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

class Database {
    constructor (url: any, dbName: any) {
        this.url = url;
        this.mongo = new MongoClient(url);
        this.database = null;
        this.databaseConnection = null;
        this.dbName = dbName;

        this.connect();
    }

    async connect() {
        this.database = await this.mongo.connect();
        this.databaseConnection = this.database.db(this.dbName);
        console.log(`Connected to ${this.dbName}`);
    }

    async disconnect() {
        await this.mongo.close();
    }

    async getCollection(name: string) {
        const collection = this.databaseConnection.collection(name);
        return collection;
    }
    
    url: any;
    mongo: any;
    database: any;
    databaseConnection: any;
    dbName: any;
}

export default Database;
```

Error

```bash
    super(message);
    ^
BSONError: cyclic dependency detected
    at new BSONError (C:\Users\...\node_modules\bson\src\error.ts:4:5)
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\...\node_modules\bson\src\parser\serializer.ts:373:34)
    at serializeInto (C:\Users\...\node_modules\bson\src\parser\serializer.ts:1013:17)
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\...\node_modules\bson\src\parser\serializer.ts:387:20)
    at serializeInto (C:\Users\...\node_modules\bson\src\parser\serializer.ts:1013:17)
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\...\node_modules\bson\src\parser\serializer.ts:387:20)
    at serializeInto (C:\Users\...\node_modules\bson\src\parser\serializer.ts:802:17)
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\...\node_modules\bson\src\parser\serializer.ts:387:20)
    at serializeInto (C:\Users\...\node_modules\bson\src\parser\serializer.ts:1013:17)
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\...\node_modules\bson\src\parser\serializer.ts:387:20)
```

## Edit & Solve

By using the `mongoose` library instead of `mongodb`, you can get rid of these problems and do much better work in a more advanced and simple experience.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error message, and in my case it was due to the fact that I was passing a Cursor from one aggregate pipeline into another aggregate pipeline.

I solved it by casting my `Cursor` into an array using the `.toArray()` function.

Note that I was getting this error message from a `mongosh` script.

You can see the full discussion here:

https://mongobooster.useresponse.com/topic/error-in-script-not-seen-when-run-in-shell